# How to get terms within sql table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to run some custom reports with Woocommerce which I have working perfectly.  Currently the reports will show you the results for all orders marked as "completed" but I am wondering how do I modify my code below to pull results from not just completed, but all order types like "completed", "canceled", "failed" and "processing"?  Currently the below code will only pull my results from orders marked as completed as seen on this line: `AND   term.slug IN ('completed')`. but how would I do this to pull from all order types like above, could I separate with comma like 'completed','processing','canceled,'failed'?  Can someone provide an example and an explanation so that I can understand this for future reference?

```
$sql = "SELECT *,
                count(*) AS 'sale_total'
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS country
                    ON order_items.order_id = country.post_id

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                    ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID

                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel ON posts.ID = rel.object_ID
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS term USING( term_id )

                WHERE posts.post_type             = 'shop_order' 
                AND   posts.post_status           = 'publish'


                AND   country.meta_key            = 'reason_for_purchase'
                AND   term.slug IN ('completed')
                AND   post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', $start_date ) . "'
                AND   post_date < '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $end_date ) ) . "'
                GROUP BY country.meta_value";
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't know for sure that you only have to change this, but in the line `term.slug IN ('completed')`, add also the other states: `term.slug IN ('completed','canceled','failed','processing')`

Comment: Thanks Filipe, I tried that before posting the questions because I thought that would be the logical approach but when I make those edits you suggested then I no longer get any results and the reports are blank?

Comment: Figured you would need more work, but not getting any results doesn't seem to make much sense, since IN evaluates if it is one of the fields in the list, and if you don't remove completed, at least those you should get from the report.That's pretty weird

Comment: Well thank you for your help, I am definitely no expert at connecting with databases but here is my attempt in its entirety: http://pastebin.com/MYHBwE7w

Comment: @FilipeSilva Wow, I made an error when typing that out, it is working now, thanks so much .. Cant believe I didnt catch it the first time :)

Comment: Super! That was easier than you thought you would be :)

Comment: I'll add my first comment as an answer so you can accept it. ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Add the other states to the query where you have: `term.slug IN ('completed')`:

Replace it with:

```
term.slug IN ('completed','canceled','failed','processing')
```